# Como faço para abrir uma janela, tipo windows explorer, a partir de um site

Tags: javascript, windows, imageview

Estou desenvolvendo um site que irá trabalhar com imagens. As imagens estão no micro local. Eu quero pegar todas as imagens (são +- 10 imagens) que estão em uma pasta e as colocar em um grid. Para depois permitir que possa ser dado um zoon. Estou achando que pelo java script eu consiga fazer isso.

Para ser entendido melhor, hoje com o programa rodando no Windows, eu chamo, a partir do programa, o Windows explorer apontando para a pasta com as imagens.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar um simples input do tipo file

Veja este exemplo

Html:

```
<form id="post-form" class="post-form" method="post">
    <label for="files">Select multiple files: </label>
    <input id="files" type="file" multiple/>
    <output id="result" />
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
window.onload = function(){
    //Check File API support
    if(window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader)
    {
        var filesInput = document.getElementById("files");
        filesInput.addEventListener("change", function(event){
            var files = event.target.files; //FileList object
            var output = document.getElementById("result");
            for(var i = 0; i< files.length; i++)
            {
                var file = files[i];
                //Only pics
                if(!file.type.match('image'))
                    continue;
                var picReader = new FileReader();
                picReader.addEventListener("load",function(event){
                    var picFile = event.target;
                    var div = document.createElement("div");
                    div.innerHTML = "<img class='thumbnail' src='" + picFile.result + "'" +
                    "title='" + picFile.name + "'/>";
                    output.insertBefore(div,null);
                });
                //Read the image
                picReader.readAsDataURL(file);
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Your browser does not support File API");
    }
}
```

Css:

```
body{
font-family: 'Segoe UI';
font-size: 12pt;
}

header h1{
font-size:12pt;
color: #fff;
background-color: #1BA1E2;
padding: 20px;

}
article
{
width: 80%;
margin:auto;
margin-top:10px;
}

.thumbnail{

height: 100px;
margin: 10px;
}
```

Resultado: http://jsfiddle.net/0GiS0/Yvgc2/

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20779983/multiple-image-upload-and-preview

Comment: Alterado nobre amigo.